# Is there any way for my chatbot to be triggered by any word in the first contact, and resend the option menu if a number is not inputed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, chatbot, whatsapp

I have the following WhatsApp chatbot script for automatic responses and predetermined options:

```
const { createBot, createProvider, createFlow, addKeyword} = require('@bot-whatsapp/bot')

const QRPortalWeb = require('@bot-whatsapp/portal')
const BaileysProvider = require('@bot-whatsapp/provider/baileys')
const MockAdapter = require('@bot-whatsapp/database/mock')

const flowEight = addKeyword("8").addAnswer(
    [
        "Answer 8",
    ],
)

const flowSeven = addKeyword("7").addAnswer(
    [
        "Answer 7",
    ],
)

const flowSix = addKeyword("6").addAnswer(
    [
        "Answer 6",
    ],
)

const flowFive = addKeyword("5").addAnswer(
    [
        "Answer 5",
    ],
)

const flowFour = addKeyword("4").addAnswer(
    [
        "Answer 4",
    ],
)

const flowThree = addKeyword("3").addAnswer(
    [
        "Answer 3",
    ],
)

const flowTwo = addKeyword("2").addAnswer(
    [
        "Answer 2",
    ],
)

const flowOne = addKeyword("1").addAnswer(
    [
        "Answer 1",
    ],
)

const flowPrincipal = addKeyword(["Hi"])
  .addAnswer([
    "Hello!",
  ])
  .addAnswer(
    [
      "Pick an option",
      " ",
      "1",
      "2",
      "3",
      "4",
      "5",
      "6",
      "7",
      "8",
    ],
    null,
    null,
    [flowOne, flowTwo, flowThree, flowFour, flowFive, flowSix, flowSeven, flowEight]
)

const main = async () => {
    const adapterDB = new MockAdapter()
    const adapterFlow = createFlow([flowPrincipal, flowOne, flowTwo, flowThree, flowFour, flowFive, flowSix, flowSeven, flowEight])
    const adapterProvider = createProvider(BaileysProvider)

    createBot({
        flow: adapterFlow,
        provider: adapterProvider,
        database: adapterDB,
    })

    QRPortalWeb()
}

main()
```

It works normally, and I only have a flowPrincipal with all of the baby flows nested inside it, this way people can send multiple answers without having to call back on the flowPrincipal (in fact, they can send a number without triggering the flowPrincipal and get an answer).

I have a problem. If someone were to type anything else, the chatbot will send the first answer: "Answer 1", as default. I would like for the chatbot to resend the option menu if the user doesn´t input any of the numbers, maybe even including a text saying: "I didn´t understand what you said, try again" and sending the option menu again.

In fact,`const flowPrincipal = addKeyword(["Hi"])` defines the word "Hi" as a trigger to display the options. If possible, I would like for any word or character, at least in the first contact, to trigger the option menu.

Also, I seem to be limited to only using 10 options (0-9), since the bot will only read the first number when including double digits.

Any help will be much obliged.